# Pop back from NavigationLink in TabView crashes tvOS app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tvos

I'm trying to make a simple tvOS app. I was testing out some basic UI code and had the following:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {  
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Subview")) {
                    Text("Subview")
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Main")
            }

            NavigationView {
                Text("Settings")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Settings")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This launches the app correctly, and I can click the NavigationLink to open the Subview. But, when I press the back/menu button the app closes and the console prints out the following error:

> [Common] Error response from snapshot request action of type 1 gave Error Domain=BSActionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. From what I have seen, I believe the above code should work (it works fine on my iOS devices). Are there any modifiers I need to add to get this to work or do I need to change the structure of my View?

I am testing this code on my Apple TV 4K (2nd gen) on tvOS 15.0.